# Safari: shortcut to close one single tab without loading the webpage?

Tags: keyboard, safari, tabs

I always have a lot of tabs open. I would like to close them quickly, but since there are a lot of them and they are very small, I don't see the “x” that closes a single Safari tab. Looks like I need to click on them one by one and reload the page.

Actually, if I hover on a tab, I can see a preview, which is helpful.

**QUESTION**

I wonder if there is a shortcut that would allow me to close one single tab after I see the preview.

Right now, if I don't want to open the web page, I can right-click on the tab and I see a menu, from which I can pick "Close Tab", but how could I achieve this more quickly?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pinch to zoom out into the tabs overview view (or use the toolbar button for it), at which point you're presented with previews of every page as well as their respective X button.

Some of the pages will probably load while in this view, but generally not in a way that slows down your interaction with the tabs, which I assume is the important thing.

Comment: Thank you, this is actually the solution I was looking for!

Comment: @Emy  While I have nothing against the tabs overview, the inability of Apple to differentiate between the concepts of zooming out a page and switching to the overview is one of the main reasons I use alternative browsers on macOS. The other is the absence of shift-clicking to select multiple tabs in order to close them or separating them into a new window. Few things are more frustrating in Safari than trying to make sure you're at 100% zoom only to be thrown into the tabs overview with *no way to reverse the action*. Hard design fail.

Comment: I know - which browser would you recommend that does not consume too much energy?

Comment: @Emy Ever since a recent update (86..?) I've found that Firefox has an acceptable energy consumption. They also have customizable toolbars which I value a lot as a frequent user of the [ - | 100% | + ] text size controls. I can't really recommend Chrome since Google e.g. doesn't know the difference between being logged into YouTube and being logged into browser sync (...apart from Google just being Google), nor can I recommend the more privacy focused Chrome-based Brave browser since apparently they can't manage to make sync work at all (macOS ↔︎ iOS in my test).

Answer (score 1):

There is no function available to access the [X] when the tab is so short. You can only click the tab to expand it, or right click and select Close Tab.